# Laravel validation form request doesn't work for conditions rule with a date field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a problem with the form request validation rules. I need to check additional data when the input date is less than 18 years ago (the user is not an adult). I write rules but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
$adultDate = Carbon::now()->subYears(18)->format('Y-m-d');
    
    $rules = [
        "brith_date" => 'required|date',
        "patron_name" => "required_if:brith_date,after,".$adultDate."|string"
    ];
    
    return $rules;
```

Comment: Should not that be : `        "patron_name" => "required_if:brith_date,after:".$adultDate."|string"`

Comment: I tried that, but it is not works too

Comment: Rule::requiredIf() will fit this way better i belive.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Rule::when($condition, $rules)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/38450)

```php
<?php
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

public function rules()
{
$adultDate = Carbon::now()->subYears(18);
$condition=Carbon::parse($this->brith_date)->isAfter($adultDate);
    return [
        'brith_date' => ['required','date'],
        
        'patron_name' => ['required' ,
          Rule::when($condition, ['string']),
         ];
}
```